# Are Wizardry 8 spells from two party members cumulative?

Tags: wizardry-8

If I were to make a party with two bishops and both were to cast the same spell, would it be more effective than a single cast?

E.g would two @ Magic Screen be better protection than just one?

Do you have a reference for your answer?

Comment: Probably not. In this sort of game a buff is either active or its not.

Comment: Well, spells/buffalo can he cast at different levels. So, if two cast at level 3, is it level 3 or 6?

Comment: If the buff is either active or not then the second casting would either have no effect or replace the buff the first spell cast. So it would be level 3.

Comment: True, if it is Boolean. But, given that it has variable casting levels, I was wondering if anyone could say definitively whether is it cumulative in Wizardry 8

Comment: It looks like the second overrides the first, as per the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spell Magic Screen doesn't stack. Casting it again just replaces the old buff with the new one.

For example I loaded up an old save and had my Valkyrie cast Magic Screen at level 3 and a level 3 buff was placed on the party as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: Wizardry 8 screenshot after casting Magic Screen at level 3]

Then I had my Bishop cast Magic Screen at level 4. The previous level 3 buff was changed to a level 4 buff:

[image: Wizardry 8 screenshot after casting Magic Screen at level]

As you can see by the tooltip in the upper right corner the Magic Screen buff affecting the party is at level 4.

I would assume all buffs and debuffs work this way. Wizardry 8 is an old school game, even more than it being 16 years old would suggest.  It's using mechanics that haven't changed much since the original Wizardry was released in 1981.  The concept of "stacking" spells or other effects is relatively modern invention.

Comment: Thanks. You are obviously an experienced Wizarder. What do you think of a 2 bishop party?

Comment: @Mawg I've only played through Wizardry 8 twice, and the last time was 9 years ago, but I expect having two bishops in your party would only add to the challenge. With this sort of game you usually can't go wrong with a balanced party. My goal when picking classes for my two playthroughs was to ensure I had all the skills covered, and having two bishops (or two of any class) would make this more difficult.